# I receive an error when I use a variable in Gnuplot to change the name of the input file within a Fortran code

Tags: plot, fortran, gnuplot, gfortran

I write a code in Fortran that allows me to draw data directly from a file using gnuplot.

```
write(10,*) 'plot "Test18.Stop.TXT" u 1:8 title "Force" lt -1 lc rgb "#808080" w lines'
```

I want to change the name of the data file every time I compile. The problem is that I do not know how to enter the file name as a variable. I have made a few attempts, such as:

```
open(11,file=Filename)
write(10,*) Filename
write(10,*) 'plot '<Filename>' u 1:8 title "Force" lt -1 lc rgb "#808080" w lines' 
close(11)
```

and

```
open(11,file=Filename)
write(10,*) Filename
write(10,*) 'plot "'Filename'" u 1:8 title "Force" lt -1 lc rgb "#808080" w lines' 
close(11).
```

Filename is a character which has the name of the file data, which should be drawn. When I compile it, I get always this error Error: **Syntax error in Write statement at <1>** (i.e. at File name).

Comment: I don't know Fortran, but how would you concatenate strings in Fortran? maybe something like this? `write(10,*) 'plot "' // Filename // '" u 1:8 title "Force" lt -1 lc rgb "#808080" w lines' 
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment again as answer, according to the StackOverflow rule: "no answers in comments".

You have to concatenate the strings. 
Without knowing Fortran but doing a short search, I guess it should be something like this:

```
write(10,*) 'plot "' // Filename // '" u 1:8 title "Force" lt -1 lc rgb "#808080" w lines'
```